# Select a value that has a greater number of values

Tags: sql, mariadb

Let's say I have a table like this one:

```
     Table T:
      A   B
     -------
   1  x | O
   2  x | O
   3  x | P
   4  y | O
   5  y | P
   6  y | P
   7  z | O
   8  z | O
   9  z | P
```

I want to select the values in column A that have a greater number of the values in column B.

For example, I want to select x, y, or z if they have more O's then P's.

I've made several attempts, but I honestly can't figure out how to do something like this.

So, how can I write a query that will retrieve what I want?

EDIT: Expected output would be:

```
  A
  -
1 x
2 z
```

Comment: please add the expected output.

Comment: For this particular sample data, what would be the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like aggregation.  Something like this:

```
select a
from t
group by a
having sum(B = 'O') > sum(b = 'P');
```

Comment: 58 seconds. That was fast!

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe it was so simple.